# Android MediaStore API to trash an image

Tags: android, mediastore

My app is a photo organizer of photos taken with the default camera app. I want it to send photos to "trash", so they can later be restored from trash in the default photos app.

Deleting images fully is shown with an example in the API docs: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#remove-item , but this deletes the image immediately and doesn't send the image to trash.

It looks like for a brief 1 month period in the beginning of 2019 there was a trash-method on MediaStore, but it was deprecated the month after: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blame/2d330f6fa8bc0888a27bf1729844be8b0fe71c8b/core/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java#L843

What API do you use to send a photo taken with the camera app to trash?

Edit: Here's a screenshot to clarify what I mean by "trash".

[image: what I mean by "trash"]

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you mean by trash and where the file would reside during trash.

Comment: I mean where photos go when you delete them in the default Android Photos app. When you press the "trash can" icon for a photo. To see "trashed" photos, you click the hamburger icon in the top left in the Photos app and press the "Trash" menu item. Added a screenshot to clarify this.

Comment: If you think 'they go somewhere' then please find out where. It can be that that app only remembers which files are trashed but leaves them where they are. You could find out with a file manager. Or use another photos app to see if it knows that trash. I think it does not.

Comment: Have you tried values.put(MediaColumns.IS_TRASHED, 1); ? And if that trash() method is gone then copy it to your code and use it. Did you try already?

Comment: @blackapps: I presume you mean like the deprecated trash() method was doing? The MediaColumns.DATE_EXPIRES constant is also deprecated, so they are obviously trying to discourage this. I tried anyway with values.put("is_trashed", 1);, and likewise for "date_expires". Did not work. The photo actually disappeared from the Photos app, but did not show up in Trash. But I appreciate the suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such API. Each app has its own private trash can implementation, you can't interact with it.

UPD: trash API is added in android R preview. 
See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#createTrashRequest(android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.util.Collection%3Candroid.net.Uri%3E,%20boolean)

Answer (score -1):

**Trash or untrash a file or folder**

The typical workflow to trash or untrash a resource is as follows:

- Request the resource metadata.
- Check if isTrashable is true.
- (Optional) Check if isTrashed is true. Calling trash on an already
  trashed resource has no effect.
- Call DriveResourceClient.trash or DriveResourceClient.untrash as
  applicable

  ```
  if (!metadata.isTrashable()) {
  showMessage(R.string.trashable_error);
  return;}

  DriveResource driveResource = metadata.getDriveId().asDriveResource();
  Task<Void> toggleTrashTask;
  if (metadata.isTrashed()) {
      toggleTrashTask = mDriveResourceClient.untrash(driveResource);
  } else {
      toggleTrashTask = mDriveResourceClient.trash(driveResource);
  }
  ```

you can follow the below link for details -

[trash and untrash](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/blob/master/drive/trash/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/drive/trash/MainActivity.java)

Comment: thanks, but I don't think this is applicable. As the heading and tags say, I am asking how to trash a photo from the MediaStore API, but what you suggested seems to be for a Google Drive API.